# htaccess redirect all subdomains to https except www

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'd like to redirect all subdomains (i've wildcard subdomains set up in apache virtualhost) to https, if http, for all except www.domain.com

Any ideas greatfully appreciated.

Here's what I have so far:

```
# Redirect subdomains to https
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(*)\. [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help you:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)localhost.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.localhost.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST} [nc]
```

First `RewriteCond`: If the website doesn't start with www

Second `RewriteCond`: Get any subdomain

Third `RewriteCond`: Check that https isn't already within the requested url

`RewriteRule`: Redirect to https version of site